# Nashorn ClassFilter only filters Java.type()?

Tags: java, nashorn

I have the following two code tests.

first: JavaTypeTest() which blocks access to java.io.File as expected.

second: JavaMethodGetFileTest() which does not block access when a java.io.File object is returned thus bypassing the filter.

is it not supposed to block anything when Java.type() is used? or is there a specific way I should be adding the objects to the engine?

expected output:

```
JavaTypeTest success: true
JavaMethodGetFileTest success: true
```

actual output:

```
JavaTypeTest success: true
Z:\eclipse ws\NashornTests\.
JavaMethodGetFileTest success: false
```

The reasoning behind this is I want a proxy class that has only allowed methods which return allowed objects but have a getInstance() method which returns a dissallowedObject so that I have access to the instance contained in the proxy without exposing it to Nashorn.

```
public class NashornTest
{
    class NashornClassFilter implements ClassFilter
    {
        public NashornClassFilter()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean exposeToScripts(String clazz)
        {
            if (clazz.equals("java.io.File")) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static class AllowedClass
    {
        public AllowedClass()
        {
        }

        public File disallowedMethod()
        {
            return new File(".");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();

        NashornClassFilter filter = new NashornTest().new NashornClassFilter();
        NashornScriptEngine engine = (NashornScriptEngine) factory.getScriptEngine(filter);

        NashornClassFilter filter1 = new NashornTest().new NashornClassFilter();
        NashornScriptEngine engine1 = (NashornScriptEngine) factory.getScriptEngine(filter1);

        System.out.println("JavaTypeTest success: " + JavaTypeTest(engine));
        System.out.println("JavaMethodGetFileTest success: " + JavaMethodGetFileTest(engine1));

    }

    public static boolean JavaTypeTest(NashornScriptEngine engine)
    {
        try
        {
            engine.eval(
                "function wrapper(){ "
                + "Java.type('java.io.File');"
                + "}");
            ((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("wrapper");
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            if(e.getCause() instanceof ClassNotFoundException) return true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean JavaMethodGetFileTest(NashornScriptEngine engine)
    {
        try
        {
            engine.put("allowed", new AllowedClass());
            engine.eval(
                "function wrapper(){ "
                        + "var file = allowed.disallowedMethod();"
                        + "print(file.getAbsolutePath());"
                        + "}");
            ((Invocable) engine).invokeFunction("wrapper");
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            if(e.getCause() instanceof ClassNotFoundException) return true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```